# Weird behavior of a custom exception in Python

Tags: python, exception

There are many questions about custom exception in Python, but I couldn't find my case.

In Python 3.7 I'm defining a class `Asterism` that has a name and a 2-axes array of 2D points. The constructor must be able to validate the input, which means that it has to raise an exception if the passed array does not have 2 axes or if it is not made by 2D elements. I consider this as a code-breaking error, so if this exception is raised the execution must be terminated.
This is the code for the classes:

```
import sys
import numpy as np

class WrongAsterism(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.message = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.message)

class Asterism:
    def __init__(self, name, points_array):
        self.name = name
        if(len(points_array.shape)!=2):
            raise WrongAsterism("The asterism must be a 2-axes numpy array. Quitting.")
        elif(points_array.shape[1]!=2):
            raise WrongAsterism("The asterism must consist of 2D points. Quitting.")
        else:
            self.points = points_array
```

I wanted to test the code, so I added the following lines:

```
try:
    np.random.seed(6)
    a = Asterism("Ursa Major", np.random.rand(9,2)*10-5)
except WrongAsterism:
    print("Error!")
    sys.exit()

print("The asterism name is {}.".format(a.name))
print("It has {} 2D points.".format(a.points.shape[0]))
print("Its points are:\n{}".format(a.points))
```

This case has a correct input, so I get:

```
The asterism name is Ursa Major.
It has 9 2D points.
Its points are:
[[ 3.92860151 -1.68020195]
 [ 3.21229123 -4.58303374]
 [-3.9234332   0.95052064]
 [ 0.29817362 -0.81192571]
 [-1.64592151  1.22519432]
 [-0.61858574  2.35882106]
 [ 0.18036412  0.788586  ]
 [ 1.45355096  4.90224271]
 [ 3.19858197 -0.86799065]]
```

However, if I try to define the object with a wrong input, for example with the line `a = Asterism("Ursa Major", np.random.rand(9,3)*10-5)`, in which the array has 2 axes but the points are 3D, or with `a = Asterism("Ursa Major", np.random.rand(9,2,3)*10-5)`, where the array has 3 axes, in both cases I get

```
Error!
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
```

instead of the expected error message.

Following the indications found in similar questions, I tried to redefine the class `WrongAsterism` also in two alternative ways, namely

```
class WrongAsterism(Exception):
    pass
```

and

```
class WrongAsterism(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg='My default message', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(msg, *args, **kwargs)
```

but nothing changes.

So, first question is "How can I get the desired custom error message?"

However, I have another problem that puzzles me badly. Among the others, I also tried to comment out the `sys.exit()`, and in this case I **always** get

```
Error!
The asterism name is Ursa Major.
It has 9 2D points.
Its points are:
[[ 3.92860151 -1.68020195]
 [ 3.21229123 -4.58303374]
 [-3.9234332   0.95052064]
 [ 0.29817362 -0.81192571]
 [-1.64592151  1.22519432]
 [-0.61858574  2.35882106]
 [ 0.18036412  0.788586  ]
 [ 1.45355096  4.90224271]
 [ 3.19858197 -0.86799065]]
```

even when I initialize the object with a wrong input! To be more precise, the code prints "Error!" only when I use the wrong input, but then it always prints the (previously used) good input.

Clearly, I'm missing some very basic issue here, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: If you catch the exception (`try..except`), then you’re suppressing the default error handling mechanism. If you want errors to be output then, you need to do it yourself. Which you’re doing, but you’re only outputting “Error!”…

Comment: Thank you `@deceze` for the explanation. Just removing the `try..except` block worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
except WrongAsterism:
    print("Error!")
    sys.exit()
```

You need to have

```
except WrongAsterism as err:
    print(err)
    sys.exit()
```